# Pyspark while joining and aggregating data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, optimization, apache-spark-sql

I am new to psypark, trying to write a code with joins and aggregations and then writing the output into a parquet. Code below:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
a = spark.sql("""select id, col1 from table1 where date between '2023-03-01' and '2023-05-31')
b = a.groupBy(id).agg(f.sum('col1').alias('cum_sum')
b.cache().count()

c = spark.sql("""select id,col2 from table2 where event_date between '2023-05-01' and '2023-05-31')
d = b.join(a, 'id', 'inner').select(a['id'],'col1','col2')
d.write.parquet('file_name.parquet')
```

Configuration: Executors = 10, Cores = 8, Executor Memory = 16g, Driver memory = 15g

[image: Caching data frame b takes around ~2.7 minutes. Each task has input size of about 25MBs and shuffle write size of ~8.5MBs. Input size is 35.3GBs and shuffle write is 12.4GBs]

UI details are for caching the data only.

Questions that I have:

1. Can the aggregation performance be further improved?
2. How do set optimal number of shuffle partitions for aggregations? Should it be simply Input size/target size? In this case if the target size is 128MB should number of partitions be (55.3 x 1024)/128 = 440 (442.4 rounded below to multiple of 8 cores that I have). 440 partitions yields the same run time as default 200 partitions.
3. While joining, should the input size be cumulative size of all data frames to be joined?
4. Assuming I had not cached data frame before the join, should shuffle partitions be changed? Meaning if there are multiple joins/aggregations in the query, should shuffle partitions parameter be changed before each operation according to the data size?
5. Is there any literature which can help me understand the internals of spark while doing aggregations/joins intuitively, like shuffling of data, map stage, reduce stage etc.?

Comment: https://books.japila.pl/apache-spark-internals/  https://analyticsdata24.files.wordpress.com/2020/02/spark-the-definitive-guide40www.bigdatabugs.com_.pdf   These should be helpful.

Comment: Will go through these, thanks.